# var elementUid = jQuery(this).find("input").attr("value"); 'undefined' is null or not an object @IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Can you please help me?

In IE10 / FF / Chrome it works like a charm, but in IE8, at this line:

```
var elementUid = jQuery(this).find("input").attr("value");
```

I get the error: ***'undefined' is null or not an object***

Thank you!

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Use `val()`, not `attr("value")`.

Comment: please post jsfiddle.So that i can test it in My IE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the event loads, after I replaced

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

with

```
$(window).load(function ()
```

the variable was loaded corectly.

Thank you for your sugestions and help!

Answer (score -1):

may be useful.

```
var elementUid = jQuery(this).find("input").prop("value");
```

Comment: You should never use prop() to get a value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr